# use Ecore/XMI editor for instance creation from Ecore metamodel

Tags: code-generation, eclipse-emf, ecore, xmi

I have a metamodel in the form of an Ecore file.
I saw in some previous projects that is possible to generate an xmi file from which it is possible to edit an instance of the Ecore metamodel.

I have generated the XMI file by clicking a class in the metamodel then "`Create Dynamic Instance ...`" but then when I click nodes in xmi file, I miss the *`*new Child*`* command that let me to create the instance fields as in the folowing picture :
[image]

Any idea how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without your metamodel and more information about exactly from which root object you created your dynamic instance, it's hard to answer properly.

Usually, if the `New Child` menu doesn't pop up, it's because your metaclass misses containment `EReference`s. The generic EMF tree editor relies on the `EStructuralFeatures` of each metaclass to display the various panels/menu to set information of your instances. If there is no containment references, then, no child can be created.

Comment: Thank you @Aranega. I would add that the EReference should be a containment